# Windows 8.1 Application Pool Identity has no Effective Access Rights

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, permissions

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, with IIS 8.5. I'm fairly new to Windows 8.1, so I don't really know what's going on.

I've copied an MVC website onto the server, created an appropriate AppPool - I'm using ApplicationPoolIdentity e.g. IIS APPPOOL\MVCSite. I've added Modify access to my web folder.

What I get is the MVC controller returns valid HTML, but none of the static resources will download. Each gives a 401.3 error. I've discovered that the Static Files is a separate module in Programs and Features, installed and rebooted, the result is the same.

If I add Everyone Modify, the static files work.

If I go to security settings > Advanced settings, I can remove Inheritence and copy the rights - I can see that my App Pool has Modify rights - there are no "Deny" rules anywhere here.

If I use the Effective rights checker and set the user to "IIS APPPOOL\MVCSite" - all the effective rights show a red X. The Permissions Tab still shows "Modify".

If there's no Inheritence and no deny rules, but something is removing the access rights, then I guess that it must be Local Machine Policy, or some new security setting, but I don't know where to look.

Does anybody know if this is a setting? or do I need to reinstall Windows?

Thanks,

Mark